# Slide next previous anchor for each photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As you can see from the below JSFIDDLE link that the next and previous functions are working fine. It is taking the user to the next or previous photos accordingly. The issue what i am facing is when user reach to the very last photo by clicking next button and then if again he press "next" button then the function is getting freeze and doesn't work anymore until refresh the page again. This is happening for the first image also that user is on the first image and if clicks the "previous" button then the page gets freeze and the function is not working anymore. Kindly check the demo and any suggestions that how can i fix the issue?

https://jsfiddle.net/jpex4908/1/

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();  

$jq(document).ready(function($jq) {
    var scrollTo = function(yoza) {
        $jq('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $jq(yoza).offset().top
       }, 300);
    };

    $jq('.next').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $jqcurrent = $jq('.home-block > .current');
        if ($jqcurrent.index() != $jq('.home-block > div').length - 1) {
            $jqcurrent.removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
            scrollTo($jqcurrent.next());
        }
    });
    $jq('.prev').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $jqcurrent = $jq('.home-block > .current');
        if (!$jqcurrent.index() == 0) {
           $jqcurrent.removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current');
            scrollTo($jqcurrent.prev());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: in your fiddle your function is working proper at last image and first image and page is not freeze on multiple time press it.after last image it's working for previous image.

Comment: How to fix the issue then? Any solutions?

Comment: @Hitesh Tripathi If you click multiple times on "Next" button when you are @ the last slide then it's not working anymore until refresh the page.

Comment: Do you want to  start it from first after last slide?

Comment: @Hitesh Tripathi Not necessary to start it from first by clicking next button. It can be deactivated also. Like when the slide will be on first slide then the "previous" button can be deactivated or disappeared so that the multiple times clicking issue can be sorted out. and same for the last slide. during the last slide the next button can be deactivated. Is it possible?